# Custom css cursor for whole page, not just over content

Tags: html, css, cursor

I have created a custom cursor that works well in firefox, and chrome, i'm not even wasting my time creating a .cur for IE, but the problem is that my page is built without any sizing because I want things moving based on %'s. The trouble I'm having, is that my cursor only displays on top of area's of content.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/basic.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="../img/s_logo.png" id="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="big_center">
        <img src="../img/b_logo.png" >
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="portrait.html">PORTRAIT</a></li>
                <li><a href="commercial.html">COMMERCIAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="fineart.html">FINE-ART</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

body{
    background-color: black;
    cursor: url(../img/cursor.png),auto;

  }




#logo{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:100;
    margin:0;   
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
.big_center{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -280px;
    margin-left: -285px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav{
    position: relative;
    top:-385px;
    left:-24px;

}
#nav ul{list-style-type: none;}

#nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:120%;
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
font-size:58px;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:106%;
color:black;
text-align:center;
/* Firefox v4.0+ , Safari v5.1+ , Chrome v10.0+, IE v10+ and by Opera v10.5+ */
text-shadow:2px -2px 0px rgb(255,102,0);
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=2,OffY=-2,Color=#ffff6600,Positive=false)";zoom:1;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=2,OffY=-2,Color=#ffff6600,Positive=false);
}

#nav a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Century Gothic","applegothic";
    font-size:58px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:106%;
    color:rgb(255,102,0);
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using {height:100%;width:100%} on the body?

Comment: have you tried using

`* {cursor: url(../img/cursor.png),auto;}`

?.. Instead of targetting just the `body`

Comment: I did add the height and width code, and it did not do anything. same with putting it the *{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cursor property on html instead of body and give html a min-height of 100%.

Comment: how would i do this in html?

Comment: You'd do it in CSS, not HTML. Oh, and my original answer should've said to put that min height on html, not body.

Comment: simply put 
html{
min-height:100%
}
?

Comment: Yes, plus include the cursor declaration that you currently have on body { } instead. Your example isn't a direct paste from your page, though, right? You have your CSS in an external file or a <style> tag, I'm assuming.